# Not printing out full contents of linked list

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm having a small bit of bother with the following method.

I want to print out the files inside a directory, and call this method from a separate main class.

Although this does work, it only prints out the first file then stops.

```
 public String viewDir(String user){
    LinkedList<String> fileNameList = new LinkedList<>();
    File actual = new File("c:\\Server\\" + user + ".");
    for( File f : actual.listFiles()){
        System.out.println(f.getName());    
        fileNameList.add(f.getName());
    }//end of advanced for loop

    for(int j = 0; j < fileNameList.size(); j++){
        return fileNameList.get(j);
    }//end of for loop
    return null;
 }
```

I am calling the method above by using:

```
System.out.println(fileInterface.viewDir(user) + "\n\n");
```

Comment: **return fileNameList.toString();**

Comment: Hi @MiteshPathak, I've noticed some of your edits in the site's review tool. Most are fine, just one thing: please do not use `code` formatting for technical terms. That kind of formatting should be reserved for actual code only. Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure will take care ot it.....
thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a method you can only execute one return statement. Since you are returning something in a loop what you are actually doing is stopping the execution of the method after the first value is returned. If you want to return all the file names then you can try constructing a String of all names and returning the entire string.

```
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      for(int j = 0; j < fileNameList.size(); j++){
          sb.append(fileNameList.get(j) + "\n");
      }//end of for loop
      return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `return` in the second loop means, that the loop and entire method get terminated. The first element of the list get returned to the caller.

The first loop should print all the files in the directory though.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you return only the first file...

```
for(int j = 0; j < fileNameList.size(); j++){
    return fileNameList.get(j);
}
```

It's like you would do (w/o the condition)

```
return fileNameList.get(0);
```

Do this instead :

```
public LinkedList<String> viewDir(String user){
    LinkedList<String> fileNameList = new LinkedList<>();
    File actual = new File("c:\\Server\\" + user + ".");

    for(File f : actual.listFiles()){
        System.out.println(f.getName());    
        fileNameList.add(f.getName());
    }//end of advanced for loop

    for(int j = 0; j < fileNameList.size(); j++){
        return fileNameList.get(j);
    }//end of for loop

    return null;
}
```

And then :

```
for (String fileName : viewDir(user)) {
    System.out.println(fileName + "\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `return` statement outside the second loop.

[The return statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) immediately stops whatever the function is doing and returns a specific value specified after the keyword `return`, so in your case, it returns a value in the first loop, and the function never got the chance of executing the second and afterward looping.

So what you should do is to get a record of the variable `j` and do `return fileNameList.get(j)` outside the second loop.